# Does "Reducing/ Minimizing your cost" make sense?

Tags: word-choice

At my company, I and my co-workers are working on a brochure for our products.
As one of the benefits our products could provide, we are trying to emphasize the fact that our customers (mostly companies and businesses in telecom industry) can reduce their operating cost using our equipment and products and we are trying to come up with a phrase for that.

In this case, will "Minimizing YOUR cost" work? One of my co-workers suggested this and I am not sure if "Your" is good. When you actually think about it, it's not YOUR cost until you pay for products at the end. How about just "operating cost"? or any other suggestions?

Comment: You won't get arrested for saying "minimizing your costs" or something similar.  That's less sterile than saying "minimizing operating costs", and the meaning will be understood just as well (if not better).

Comment: Strictly speaking, *minimize* means reducing to the absolute lowest level possible. But from a marketing perspective, I guess anything goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product that clearly performs better than your competition at saving costs then the best approach is to show off those hard earned numbers.  50% less maintenance, consumes 30% less power, etc.

If you have a run of the mill product all you have is hype and puffery so you play to their fantasies.  Show them on a beach drinking mai tai's checking their phone only to find out there is nothing to do because the product is working perfectly.

Or just say, "minimize your costs with xyz's latest product", because yeah, your English is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found it very helpful (though I couldn't press the 'up' button because my reputation is below 15). I appreciate it.

Comment: That's expected.  Focus on learning how we do things here.  Read the [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and keep posting.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are asking whether the phrase "reduce your cost" is a contradiction in terms because you consider *cost* to not be *yours* until the time of payment.

Let's look at the definition of cost:

> **Cost** *noun*
>   1 An amount that has to be paid or spent to buy or obtain something: *we are able to cover the cost of the event*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cost)

Payment doesn't have to be due for someone to consider the costs, so to answer your question, **the phrase *reduce your costs* makes sense** and is idiomatic, particularly in the context of marketing.

If you are concerned with accuracy (a commendable trait), then although *minimise your cost* also makes sense, it should only be used when you are able to demonstrate that their costs will actually be minimised by using your products.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your comment. Now I realize I should look at a dictionary first, before anything else. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Happy to help :) . Have a look at [this link](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/notes-to-reviewers-trial-version-2-1). It's intended for people who have had their questions put on hold, but take a look anyway at the resources linked from item 2. There are links to dictionaries, style guides and more!